# Share an object instance between multiple session/application instances in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am developing a project for a log monitor and I am using an ASP.NET application with [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

The main objective of the application is to provide a monitor of error logs in multiple clients across different locations (LCD monitors). Every moment when a log error is created in database, the application should notify all the clients with the new error.

I am wondering to create a static `Timer` variable in the web application, that will be started by the `Application_Start` method.

But, knowing the application will have a single thread per session, I think the web server will have a lot of timers running together.

I need to know how to make this `Timer` instance **unique for all the session instances** in the web server.

Comment: What's the timer used for? Every interval it'll check the logging db for new errors?

Comment: @Psytronic Yes, it will check the database for a new error, and, if it has a new error, the SignalR connection will broadcast to all clients.

Comment: Why do you want a unique timer then? Wouldn't the one timer suffice, as you can push messages to all connected clients at once with signalR

Comment: Creating a new timer instance per session will create multiple timer instances in the server, then, it will have multiple timers checking the database together.

Comment: But you only need the one timer, as you only need the one database check going on, and signalr can push to all connected clients. Also, take a quick read of this; http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Yes I only need one timer, is that the question. Every time a session is created by a request to the controller action, the `Application_Start`method will create a new instance of the timer. I need one only instance.

Comment: Application_Start is not triggered by a new session, but by, um, the application start. You don't have the problem you think you have.

Comment: @Filip please post this comment as an answer for my question, beacuse it is the real answer what I've looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application_Start is not triggered by a new session, but by the [start of the application](http://aspalliance.com/1114_Understanding_the_Globalasax_file.all). If you initialize your timer in Application_Start, you don't need to worry about multiple timer instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance class that has a timer.

For instance:

```
public class MyTimerHolder
    {
        private static Lazy<MyTimerHolder> _instance = new Lazy<MyTimerHolder>(() => new MyTimerHolder());
        private readonly TimeSpan _checkPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        private IHubContext _hubProxy;
        // Threaded timer
        private Timer _timer;

        public MyTimerHolder()
        {
            _timer = new Timer(CheckDB, null, _checkPeriod, _checkPeriod);
        }

        public void BroadcastToHub(IHubContext context)
        {
            _hubProxy = context;
        }

        public void CheckDB(object state)
        {
            if (_hubProxy != null)
            {
                // Logic to check your database

                _hubProxy.Clients.All.foo("Whatever data you want to pass");
            }
        }

        public static MyTimerHolder Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _instance.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can change the hubContext at any point from any method.  So lets say you want to broadcast to clients connected to hub "MyDBCheckHub".  At any point in your application all you have to do is:

```
MyTimerHolder.Instance.BroadcastToHub(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyDBCheckHub>());
```

You could throw this in your application start or wherever you please, there'll only be 1 instance of MyTimerHolder within the app domain.